blobstore.BlobstoreUploadHandler uploaded file not available on request.environ
I'm following the Google Blobstore api documentation for flask (which works as expected) and trying to get the uploaded file info:


class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload = self.get_uploads(request.environ)[0]
        photo = PhotoUpload(blob_key=upload.key())
        photo.put()

        logging.info(f"upload: {upload}")



however on the handler I have implemented the file is not available on request.environ context. This is my handler:


@upload_testing_bp.route("/")
def upload():
      upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url("/upload_testing/upload_photo", gs_bucket_name="test")

      response = make_response(jsonify(upload_url))
      response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store"
      response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

      return response

@upload_testing_bp.route("/upload_photo", methods=["POST"])
def upload_photo():
        upload = self.get_uploads(request.environ)[0]



And this is the upload button:
            <div class="button hidden-upload" type="button" ng-show="dr.folder.folder.rights[1]" ng-click="!filereader_available && no_filereader()">
                <span class="material-icons btn-icon file_upload"></span>
                <span class="btn-icon-label">Upload</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" dr-upload="" ng-if="filereader_available">
            </div>

And the POST request to the generated url:
    function upload(file, backoff) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("folder", folder_key_str);
    fd.append("file_name", file_item.name);
    fd.append("files[]", file);

    $http.post(url, fd, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        timeout: 1000 * (min_timeout + Math.pow(1.5, backoff))
    })

Any idea what could be wrong on my implementation? The POST request seems to be as expected and the file is not available on request.environ but is avaible on request.files['files[]']

After further debugging, the file is actually available on request.environ, however on the same POST request I was also trying to send other parameters, and as soon I get the value of those parameters, like:request.form.get('file_name') the file is not available anymore on the current request.environ, same happens the other way around, if I get the file info first: blob_info = self.get_uploads(request.environ)[0] the other form parameters are not available anymore.
A solution I found for it was to send the other request parameters as query parameters and then get them as: file_name = request.args.get('file_name')
And this because environ['wsgi.input'] is a stream like object
